# Is it worth initializing constants in the correct type? (I.e. 10UL for unsigned long)

Tags: c++

As someone who isn't familiar with digging into post-compiled code, I'm curious if I am wasting my time for zero gain by initializing variables values to the correct type.

Suppose I have class with an unsigned long member.

```
class A {
public:
  A()
private:
  unsigned long my_val;
};
```

Let's suppose I'm going to initialize `my_val` to zero. Does it make any difference *at all* if I use `0` or `0UL`?

```cpp
class A {
public:
  A()
private:
  unsigned long my_val{0};
};
// or 
class A {
public:
  A()
private:
  unsigned long my_val{0UL};
};
```

What about in line declarations?

```cpp
// some method elsewhere in my program
void B() {
  unsigned long b_val = 0;
  // or 
  unsigned long b_val = 0UL;
}
```

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it makes no difference at all, whatsoever.

An integer constant's type is the smallest type that will fit it, but no less than an `int`. Assigning a value to a wider integer type automatically converts. So, pedantically, a 0 value that's an `int` gets converted to an `unsigned long` 0 and gets used to initialize an `unsigned long` value. Alternatively, an explicit 0 value that's `unsigned long` from the beginning gets used to initialize the same `unsigned long` value.

The end result is the same, and the former case will have the compiler perform the conversion itself, rather to emit explicit code to do that. The end result can be expected to be the same exact code, generated in both instances.